# PHP preg_match pattern - Small issue

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need a pattern which matches

> youtube.com/watch?v=iNAMI8DQc8M

and

> youtu.be/iNAMI8DQc8M

it should return the video id, in this case **iNAMI8DQc8M**

I tried this pattern:

```
youtu[.*][be|be\.com]\/+(.+)
```

but that does not work, I am not really good with regex.

Comment: Are you here to learn or to get a solution just for copy-pasting? (not irony, depending on your aim the answer would be different)

Comment: I would be happy with a answer which includes a working code, but explains ever part of it, so I can also understand it :)

Comment: @Michael If you learn regex, this won't be that difficult of a task

Comment: I know, I don't use it that often and can get some patterns on my own, but this one is a but to hard for me ;) Thanks for the downvote tho.

Comment: "and can get some patterns on my own", "Thanks for the downvote tho" --- I honestly cannot think of something simpler than this. So I bet downvote here is because the regex 101 which covers all what you need to answer this question yourself would take less than half an hour to pass through.

Comment: Well, anything looks easy if you know it ;) To be honest, the working pattern looks not easy to me ;) You can't be good at everything, so I focus on the thing that I really use very often. There is not much time, as a student with your own business ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = 'youtube.com/watch?v=iNAMI8DQc8M';
$id = get_id($str);

function get_id($str) {
    $matches = array();

    if (preg_match('/youtu\.?be\/?(\.com\/watch\?v=)?([\w]+)/', $str, $matches)) {
        $id = $matches[2];
    }
    return $id;
}
```

It's extremely tolerant, but it works.

We know youtu will be there no matter what, so there it is. `youtu`

The first part checks for a . before be. It could be there, but doesn't need to be there. `\.?be`

There is a check for the .com/watch?v= part, too, which is also unnecessary, but okay to have. `(\.com\/watch\?v=)?`

After that, we match the video ID. `([\w]+)`

Comment: Thanks, sadly it also returns ".com/watch?v=" in an array, that should not be happen.

Comment: @Michael: put `?:` into the beginning of first matching group

Comment: I added the necessary PHP code to make it into a working function for you.

Answer (score 0):

Always use the tools that are specific for your issue. In this case is `parse_url();`

```
print_r( parse_url('http://' . $youtube); );
```

Regex is discourage when there is an appropiate parser for your task

Comment: I agree. :-) The poster requested a pattern, though, so I provided that. I'm one who votes for using a hammer to hit a nail instead of using a screw driver.

Comment: The reason why I need a pattern is the fact that it is used on many different URLs and they all need to provide the ID in the second array, that won't work with parse_url cause then there would be many different keys in the array ;) But otherwise I totally agree :)

Comment: if there is a single key, you can easly extract it with parse url even if it is different

Answer (score 0):

This is the right expression, corrected from user mts7's answer.

```
/youtu\.?be\/?(\.com\/watch\?v=)?/
```

I don't know much about regular expressions either. But I used in this case an online regexp validator. You can check this expression working here:

http://www.regexr.com/39u0c